# Detect screenshot event on Windows with Python

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm creating an application in which users can select a specific part of the screen to screenshot, which will then get processed. The (naive) way that I'm doing this currently is using the pyautogui library to simulate the windows shortcut for that:

```
    def take_screenshot():
        time.sleep(1)
        # Windows hotkey for selective manual screenshot
        pyautogui.hotkey('win', 'shift', 's')
        time.sleep(8)
        # return retrieved screenshot from clipboard
        return ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
```

This is obviously a very hacky solution, as i am just halting the program for some amount of time until the use has selected a specific area using the screenshot. But i'm wondering is what the best way is to handle this? I want to wait until the user is done taking a screenshot to process it, so i was thinking there is a way to listen to windows events to know whether a screenshot is still being taken?

Comment: That tool is not designed to be automated.  If you want to grab a screenshot, just grab it.  It only takes a few GDI calls:

Comment: i want the program to be interactive, the purpose is to extract text from the selected part of the screen for note-taking, so it requires some manual selection